# Onde estou errando nesse select?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Fiz o Select abaixo só que ele não está somando pela coluna correta, onde estou errando?

Na minha estrutura tenho o campo dtConcat e o campo dtConcat2 (essas datas são diferentes uma é para data do pedido e a outra é para a data que efetivou a venda) ele está somando a coluna dtConcat2 mesmo eu colocando no select que quero o mes e ano da coluna dtConcat

```
SELECT cat.id, cat.nome_vendedor, MONTH (dtConcat) AS mes, YEAR (dtConcat) AS ano,
SUM( IF( mov.tipo_venda =  'Atacado', mov.total, 0 ) ) AS Atacado
FROM lc_controle AS mov
INNER JOIN vendedor AS cat ON cat.id = mov.vendedor
where mov.exportado = 'Sim'
GROUP BY ano, mes, cat.nome_vendedor 
ORDER BY nome_vendedor, ano, mes
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Robert.
Talvez o problema seja que o Group By esta utilizando o nome das colunas renomeadas e dentro da mesma query você tenha que utilizar os campos exatos do From que esta utilizando.

Se você separar o código fazendo primeiro o Inner join de forma completa, gerar uma base e depois rodar com o group by em uma segunda etapa funcione.

Porem este processo não será tão rápido por dividirá em 2 etapas mas funciona.

Comment: valeu era isso mesmo,,,as vezes coisas simples complicam..kkk
Resolvi assim:
SELECT DISTINCT cat.id, cat.nome_vendedor, MONTH (dtConcat) AS dt_mes, YEAR (dtConcat) AS dt_ano, 
SUM( IF( mov.dtConcat , mov.total, 0 ) ) AS Atacado 
FROM lc_controle AS mov 
INNER JOIN vendedor AS cat ON cat.id = mov.vendedor 
where mov.exportado = 'Sim' 
GROUP BY cat.nome_vendedor, dt_mes, dt_ano
ORDER BY nome_vendedor, dtConcat